# Unable to trigger re-composition after re-assigning mutableStateList inside a coroutine scope

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I'm still a bit of a beginner with Jetpack compose and understanding how re-composition works.
So I have a piece of code calls below inside a `ViewModel`.

`SnapshotStateList`

```
var mutableStateTodoList = mutableStateListOf<TodoModel>()
    private set
```

during construction of the view model, I execute a room database call

```
init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        fetchTodoUseCase.execute()
            .collect { listTypeTodo ->
                mutableStateTodoList = listTypeTodo.toMutableStateList()
            }
    }
}
```

then I have an action from a the ui that triggers adding of a new Todo to the list and expecting a re-composition from the ui that shows a card composable

```
fun onFabClick() {
    todoList.add(TodoModel())
}
```

I can't figure out why it doesn't  trigger re-composition.

However if I modify the init code block below, and invoke the `onFabClick()` action, it triggers re-composition

```
init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        fetchTodoUseCase.execute()
            .collect { listTypeTodo ->
                mutableStateTodoList.addAll(listTypeTodo)
            }
    }
}
```

or this, taking out the re-assigning of the `mutableStateList` outside of the coroutine scope also works (triggers re-composition).

```
init {
    // just trying to test a re-assigning of the mutableStateList property
    mutableStateTodoList = emptyList<TodoModel>().toMutableStateList()
}
```

Not quite sure where the problem if it is within the context of coroutine or `SnapshotStateList` itself.

Everything is also working as expected when the code was implemented this way below, using standard list inside a wrapper and performing a copy (creating new reference) and re-assigning the list inside the wrapper.

```
var todoStateWrapper by mutableStateOf<TodoStateWrapper>(TodoStateWrapper)
    private set
```

Same init{...} call

```
init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        fetchTodoUseCase.execute()
            .collect { listTypeTodo ->
                todoStateWrapper = todoStateWrapper.copy (
                    todoList = listTypeTodo
                )
            }
    }
}
```

To summarize, inside a coroutine scope, why this works

```
// mutableStateList
todoList.addAll(it)
```

while this one does not?

```
 // mutableStateList
 todoList = it.toMutableStateList()
```

also why does ordinary list inside a wrapper and doing `copy()` works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mutable state in Compose can only keep track of updates to the containing value. Here is simplified code on how `MutableState` could be implemented:

```
class MutableState<T>(initial: T) {
    private var _value: T = initial
    
    private var listeners = MutableList<Listener>

    var value: T
        get() = _value
        set(value) {
            if (value != _value) {
                _value = value
                listeners.forEach {
                    it.triggerRecomposition()
                }
            }
        }
    
    fun addListener(listener: Listener) {
        listeners.add(listener)
    }
}
```

When the state is used by some view, this view subscribes to updates of this particular state.

So, if you declare the property as follows:

```
var state = MutableState(1)
```

and try to update it with `state = 2.toMutableState()` (this is analogous to your `mutableStateTodoList = listTypeTodo.toMutableStateList()`), `triggerRecomposition` cannot be called because you create a new object which resets all the listeners. Instead, to trigger recomposition you should update it with `state.value = 2`.

With `mutableStateList`, the analog of updating value is any method of `MutableList` interface that updates containing list, including `addAll`.

Inside `init` it works because no view is subscribed to this state so far, and that's the only place where methods such as `toMutableStateList` should be used.

It is important to always define mutable states as immutable property with `val` in order to prevent such mistakes. To make it mutable only from view model, you can define it like this, and make updates on `_mutableStateTodoList`:

```
private val _mutableStateTodoList = mutableStateListOf<TodoModel>()
val mutableStateTodoList: List<TodoModel> = _mutableStateTodoList
```

The only exception when you can use `var` is using `mutableStateOf` with delegation - this is where you can use it with `private set` because in that case the delegation does the work for you by not modifying the container, but only it's `value` property. Such method cannot be applied to `mutableStateListOf`, because there's no single `value` field that's responsible for the data in case of list.

```
var someValue by mutableStateOf(1)
    private set
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, though I'm a little bit aware of how compose observes/subscribes to a state object, I just can't figure out why it doesn't work when I do it inside a coroutine scope `scope.launch { todoList = emptyList<TodoModel>().toMutableStateList() }`, while if I just simply call the same statement outside of the scope and it does trigger a re-composition?. Note: these 2 different configuration will still be followed by the same call to `todoList.add(TodoModel())`

Comment: I just can't figure out why it doesn't work if I do it inside an emission of a coroutine flow and it does when I put it outside

Comment: @zab.y it's not related to coroutine, I think my answer is clear at this point - in `init` the view is not yet subscribed to the updates, that's why it "works", but in coroutine it happens later, so you flush all the subscribers